# how to edit modal image(lightbox) to be fully responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, lightbox

To get you into my problem let me explain it.

I want to have a grid of images, where click on each will pop a modal window with the img. To close this window I want to click anywhere around the image.

The problem is, that when the window is larger, the image starts to expand and it creates an area, that is usually (in the codepen it is red) invisible, but still image. So that when I try to click outside the img I cant, because I still unknowingly target the IMG. How do I solve this?

(I have the logic in JS set if (e.target.tagName !== IMG ) remove class.)

```
`https://codepen.io/Kapaak/pen/XWjJxam `
```

Comment: You can listen to resize events in `window.onresize`

Comment: but the problem is not in the resizing. The problem is that I cant target the space around the image, because some of the space is invisibly covered by the img

Comment: It would be best if you made an MVP of it on your post using S.O.'s code editor. That way we can see it in action and better help you.

Comment: ok I will upload it

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kapaak/pen/XWjJxam , when you click on any img, you will get the red color behind it, which is still type IMG

Comment: you could think it otherwise in the way of sizing your image : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oNzgade

Comment: object-fit only resize the view of the image inside its tag, but the tag doesn't shrink to feet to the rescaled view.

Comment: your approach works perfectly, but I still dont understand why my code didnt work like this

Comment: and is there any other way how to create such "effect" ? 
I am not used to use vmin , so is there any alternative?

Comment: what I for example dont like about this is that if you keep changing your height, it will make the img shorter and shorter, but I want it to have some min-height and in here I cant set min-height